# How to extract the children nodes of create table

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have the following *xml* file.

```
<databaseChangeLog>
 <changeSet author="debdipta.h (generated)" id="1442927616936-399">
        <createTable tableName="SI_FORWARDING_EVENT_HISTORY_AU">
            <column name="FORWARDING_ID_O" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="FORWARDING_ID_N" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="ASSIGNMENT_ID_O" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="ASSIGNMENT_ID_N" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_O" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_N" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="ORIGINAL_USER_ID_O" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="ORIGINAL_USER_ID_N" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="FORWARD_FROM_USER_O" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="FORWARD_FROM_USER_N" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="FORWARD_TO_USER_O" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="FORWARD_TO_USER_N" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="COMMENTS_O" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)"/>
            <column name="COMMENTS_N" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)"/>
            <column name="XML_O" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)"/>
            <column name="XML_N" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)"/>
            <column name="CREATED_BY_O" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="CREATED_BY_N" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="CREATION_DATE_O" type="date"/>
            <column name="CREATION_DATE_N" type="date"/>
            <column name="AUDIT_TRAIL_REASON" type="VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR)"/>
            <column name="TRANSACTION_TYPE" type="VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="deb.h" id="4588999797">
       </changeSet>
      </databaseChangeLog>
```

I want to display the children nodes of the element changeSet i.e.

```
createTable
column
column
...
column
```

But the code I have written is not showing me anything.

```
p

ackage com.xml.diff;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;


    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    public class isolateXML {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db=dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document dom=db.parse(new FileInputStream("E:/1.xml"));
        Element ele=dom.getDocumentElement();
        ele.normalize();
        NodeList list=ele.getElementsByTagName("changeSet");
        for(int i=0;i<list.getLength();i++){
            Node r=list.item(i);
            NodeList rs=r.getChildNodes();
        for(int j=0;j<rs.getLength();j++){  
            Node k=rs.item(j);
            System.out.println(k.getNodeName());
        }

            }

          }




    }
```

The only output I am getting is

```
 #text
    createTable
    #text
    #text
```

Can anyone tell me exactly what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please use a debugger to look at the content of `ele`, `list` and `r`.

Comment: tried it. But the number of childnodes for the element changeSet is shown as 2 only. I don't understand why it is showing this.

Answer (score 0):

I would explore your node tree, ignoring the empty text nodes.

```
public static void exploreNode(Node node) {
    //Ignore empty text node
    if (node instanceof Text) {
        String value = node.getNodeValue().trim();
        if (value.equals("")) {
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        NodeList childrens = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < childrens.getLength(); i++) {
            exploreNode(childrens.item(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there are exceptions.Its unable to continue the loop.

Comment: Somewhere its getting the value null.  I am unable to understand exactly where.

Comment: What was the exact problem with the previous code?Where was it getting null text node??

Comment: It's because `node.getNodeValue()` was returning null on the `column` nodes.